# Is my Hard Drive okay now? Critical SMART warning

Tags: hard-drive

[Hwinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com) showed my Hard Disk Drive (HDD) S.M.A.R.T result and I saw this warning with a caution sign:

> [C5] Current Pending Sector Count: 100/Always OK, Worst: 100 (Data =
> 8,0,0)

After doing some research online, I came to know that this is an uncorrectable sector warning [current pending sector count warning] and this may result the HDD to damage. However, I backed up my all the data and run this command with administrator privilege in the windows command prompt to secure erase the HDD:

> `format [drive letter]: /P:3`

I had 4 partitions so I cleaned them all, deleted all the partitions and re-created a single partition using disk manager. I put that drive letter in the cmd.

After formatting the whole HDD (it took about 9 hours to complete), I again run Hwinfo and it is showing this result:

[Screenshot showing result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgdz5.png)

> [C5] Current Pending Sector Count:  100/Always OK, Worst: 100

(with a green tick mark.)

Does that mean my HDD is okay now? What the result is showing?

[SMART result after performing format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx2Wa.png)

Comment: “Does that mean my HDD is okay now? ” - No; It will eventually fail. HDDs only come with a limited number of extra sectors which are used which their firmware determine a sector can no long be used. Why risk it HDDs are cheap

Comment: Current Pending Sectors are not necessarily uncorrectable. They are sectors that have experienced an error, but have not yet been reallocated. run chkdsk/fsck in thorough mode to attempt to reallocate them. then you can tell if you have any uncorrectable sectors. if they are successfully reallocated, and the reallocated sector count is below warning, then you can probably use the drive a little while longer, but you need to watch the pending and reallocated sector counts, as bad sectors tend to increase exponentially once you get more than a few, and they are potentially destroying your data.

Comment: & now would be a good time to make sure your backup is up to date.